# How to make website responsive on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

my website looks great on desktop however I'm having trouble scaling it perfectly on mobile devices. I went ahead and put the meta tag on every page, but its still not scaling perfectly.

Can anyone help me out on how to accomplish this? Or perhaps a good video tutorial? Pic has been added, I'm using the a responsive app to help me out.

Also, I'm new to web development, is it terrible that I got my website perfectly on desktop and not mobile apps? Do most web developers format both desktop and mobile apps at the same time? Or is it not too terrible that I'm fixing this at the end? Just trying to learn best practice here. 
 [image: Example]

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*: before,
*: after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: url();
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
  font-family: "Quicksand";
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #2F3A3B;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

navbar-brand {
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  margin-top: -8px;
  border-radius: 5.0em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-left: -5em;
  margin-bottom: -8px
}

.avatar {
  border-radius: 5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.intro {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 65px 0 65px;
  background-color: #2A2332;
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: medium;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
  position: center;
}

h4 {
  font-size: -.5em;
  position: center;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.bigicon {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #808080;
}

.input-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: .5rem;
  top: .7rem;
  /* Keep icon in center of input, regardless of the input height */
}

.btn {
  margin-right: 12em;
}

#message {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.form-control {
  text-indent: 2rem;
  width: 75%;
}

.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Contact</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--Homepage link-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html"><img class="avatar" src="images/Originals/avatar.jpg" alt>Munoz Designs</a>

    <!--Toggle Button-->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

    <!--Navbar links-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
          </li>

          <!--Social Media Icons-->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.instagram.com/eddiearkmunoz/" title="Follow on Instagram" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/eddie-munoz-351a9428/" title="Follow on Linkedin" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://twitter.com/arkadiusart" title="Follow on Twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="https://eddiemunoz.deviantart.com/gallery/" title="Follow on Deviant Art" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-deviantart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.artstation.com/ed209" title="Follow on ArtStation" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" title="Email">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--Intro of Contact-->

  <div class="intro">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    <h4>If you would like to work with me, send me a message!</h4>
  </div>

  <!--Contact Form-->

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 mx-auto">
        <div class="well well-sm">
          <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

            <fieldset>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
                  <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <input id="fname" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <label for="fname" class="fa fa-user input-icon bigicon"></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
                  <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                    <label for="email" class="fa fa-envelope-o input-icon bigicon"></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
                  <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="3"></textarea>
                    <label for="message" class="fa fa-pencil input-icon bigicon"></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center mx-auto">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-md">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So far 2 comments have been deleted, does anyone know why this is? I really appreciate reading everyone's response. This helps so much. I wish all comments would stay?

Comment: mine was an accident i re-posted it i was trying to edit it lol.

Comment: Thanks Jonny, lol. Yours was very detailed and wanted to try it out on sublime. haha...

Comment: No problem any questions you have  i'm glad to help sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What's strange is all other pages on my website are working in mobile setting, except the contact page. I see it populates perfectly in mobile and then quickly reverts back to desktop mode ? Any ideas as to why? I wonder if it has anything to do with the contact form itself?

Comment: i would really have to see it its hard to say.  you can post that as a specific question and ill help you with it.  This one is really broad because you can do so much its hard to get specific about what you need.  but i would to have a look

Comment: try this in the class on container that holds your form display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;

Comment: would I add that in css or html?

Comment: the css.  make sure it is the parent container of the form

Comment: Tried this: .container{
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  
}
  
Populated perfectly, then disappeared to the desktop mode(tiny view).

Comment: Not sure i follow. Do you mean it minimizes to your desktop toolbar?

Comment: Hi Johnny, it minimizes like the picture I attached. When I reload, for a second it's perfectly sized on the device then disappears and is sized like the attached photo.

Comment: What software you are using more than likely has something to do with it.  what editor are you designing in? Did you try it online or through the editor view, or maybe some setting.

Comment: I tested from localhost and it and it views fine.

Comment: Mobile viewports encompass various sizes, most conventionally from 320px to 450px. When you resize your screen viewport, where does the form actually snap? Do you get the left alignment (as for your screen) only for 320px viewports? I got to say I went through your code and there are a lot of inconsistencies and conflicting CSS declarations. I have also noticed you have added a lot of dependencies in your app (bootstrap, jquery, etc.); do you get any errors in the console at all?

Comment: No, I actually don't have any errors in my console at all. I'm using Chrome's 'Inspect' feature and I size it down as a iphone and ipad. Ipad and desktop are fine, but for mobile it populates fine, then switches back to a distant desktop view. It must be my settings on the inspection feature. I'll keep playing around with it. As I said 'rags1riches' I'm new with this. This is actually my first website ever. So yes, there may be some inconsistencies with my CSS. You can help by pointing them out.

Comment: I got it to work. The only thing I did different was put the meta tag in the php file. ? Anyways, it looks perfect now on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just starting out, many will tell you to a then b, or b then a.
My personal experience is that you should focus on how to make a website for a desktop environment first. You'll learn the basics. Slowly, but you'll definitely get a grasp of it.

Once you've completely learned HTML, CSS and **some** JS. I'd suggest you start learning Mobile Web Design.

Some sites to get you going

- [TOP](https://theodinproject.com)
- [Free Code Camp](https://freecodecamp.org)
- [Code Academy](https://codeacademy.com)

P.S.
Don't worry much about which Text Editor to choose. Many will say *A* has more features than *B*. Don't let features stray you away from the path of learning to web develop. You're main focus should be HOW to create a web page. How to design it. How to Debug it. How to modify it. How to add animation, etc!

Answer (score 0):

You need to design things with %(Width, Height, etc.) as much as possible, and You need to explore @media queries, You are on the right track. Here is an example. Dont forget to use !important or it will not work.  This tells the site/app to ignore previous css if the condition is met(in this case resolution size)

```
 @media only screen and (max-width:1000px){/*if it is 1000px change the font to 12 pt and so on for each resolution you need.*/
 .centered{font-size:12pt!important;}
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width:800px){/*if it is 800px change the font to 11 pt and so on for each resolution you need.*/
 .centered{font-size:11pt!important;}
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width:600px){
 .centered{font-size:10pt!important;}
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width:400px){
 .centered{font-size:9pt!important;}
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width:200px){
 .centered{font-size:8pt!important;}
 }

 .centered{ 
 position: absolute; 
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:14pt;
 }
```

The HTML

```
 <div class="centered">Hello</div>
```

Note you can do this for width, height, margins and everything else. Hope it helps.  You will have to apply this to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You should be building progressively. Meaning Element for element, you test on each of your target medias as you make changes. That way you can identify issues. Otherwise you end up with a huge structure where there could be about 30 different problems and you would need to change every DOM element to find where the issues are.